# Регулярка на PHP - если значения нет

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть регулярка:

```
/(?=Rank=(\d+))(?=.*BL=(\d+))/
```

Нужно вытащить значения у параметров Rank и BL

> Rank=10 VRank=7 Rep=98% BL=10

Но значения BL, иногда может не быть (например: Rank=4 VRank=7 Rep=98%), и тогда регулярка не срабатывает. Не силен в регулярках, как поправить?

Comment: Надо добавить знак вопроса к выражению, выбирающему BL.
    
    /(?=Rank=(\d+))(?=.*BL=(\d+))?/

Comment: Проверил на regex101.com, не сработало, в скрипте тоже. Может быть, модификатор нужно добать?

Comment: @aliokero эм, или я чего-то не знаю, или мир другой стал %)

Вот проверьте: http://goo.gl/xD2fiA

Comment: Да, в предоставленом вами облаке все работает, но на localhost почему-то не заводится. Можно как-то решить эту узкопоставленную задачу другой регуляркой или способом? Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Отлично! Все заработало) Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @aliokero, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@aliokero](/users/24240/aliokero)](/users/24240/aliokero)  Сделайте так:

```
(?:Rank=(\d+))(?:.*BL=(\d+))?
```

Comment: какуюю смысловую нагрузку несет сочетание'?:' ?

Comment: @Isaev незапоминающие кавычки, иначе было бы так:

    [1]=> string(7)"Rank=10"                                 
    [2]=> string(2) "10"                            
    [3]=> string(22) " VRank=7 Rep=98% BL=10"
    [4]=> string(2) "10"

Comment: @lampa, так можно же их просто не писать... Чем будет отличаться такой вариант:

    Rank=(\d+)

от такого:

    (?:Rank=(\d+))

Comment: @Isaev можно и не писать. Ничем не отличается.

Comment: @lampa, а в общем полезно, не знал об этом... Наверное, и время экономится, если не сохраняются промежуточные результаты.